# Insert JavaScript file if the IE document.mode < 8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I have the following script within the head of my ASP.Net page. This will only include script file if the IE version is less than 8, but if the IE version is 10 and document mode is 7 then this script will not get included.

**Is there a way to include dynamically javascript file based on document.mode value using similar notation?**

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
  <script src="xyz.js">
<![endif]-->
```

EDIT 1: the following gave unterminated string error in IE 10.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title></title>
  <script>/*<![CDATA[*/if(document.documentMode==7)document.write("<script src=\"xyz.js">
    </script>");/*]]>*/</script>
 </head>
```

Dynamically Include a javascript file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an IE conditional comment, but it will dynamically include a JavaScript file based on the documentMode and will not affect other browsers. Choose which one you like best:

```
<script>/*<!--*/if(document.documentMode==7)document.write('<script src="xyz.js"><\/script>');/*-->*/</script>

<script>/*<![CDATA[*/if(document.documentMode==7)document.write('<script src="xyz.js"><\/script>');/*]]>*/</script>

<script>if(document.documentMode==7)document.write('<script src="xyz.js"><\/script>');</script>
```

Thanks @Jonathan Lonowski for the last option!

Comment: This will overwrite the current document with a script tag.

Comment: @Vache Only after the `document` is "*ready*" and closed. Until then, it'll modify it.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski This is correct, I have just tested the code in IE10, and it does work.

Comment: Alexander - Will this cause the script to load asynchronously and can I include it in the head section? Which is the best location in a web page ( head or body) to include it?

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski: I noticed this when I tested it, and added html comments, I'll add your method and another method to my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Ah. Gotcha. Haven't seen comments used for that before. So, good to know.

Comment: @Sunil: I don't believe it will load asynchronously (you could add the defer attribute to the printed string), but you can definitely include it in the head section.

Comment: I have just tested, it does load synchronously as expected, but if you wish to have it load asynchronously, use '<script src="xyz.js" defer></'+'script>' in the document write statement.

Comment: Alexander - Wow that's great. Brilliant answer. It should not throw errors in FF or Google Chrome. Thanks. I was wanting to include a html5 javascript file in my page if user had IE 10 but was in document mode of 7. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Alexander - I tested this in IE 10 and it gives an unterminated string constant error. I tried the first 2 versions of your answer.

Comment: Version 2 does appear to have this issue, I'm not sure why but I've removed it. The other 2 are working fine for me. Do you have some example code?

Comment: Alexander - Please look under Edit 1 in my post to see the sample that failed with one your possible answers.

Comment: Ah, because there was no type attribute on the script tag, it was terminating at the first occurrence of </script> in the second method. I have fixed the line in my answer. All you need it <\/script> in the document.write command instead of </script>.

Comment: Alexander - Excellent. So a back slash was added to insert a special character. Even first version needs this.